# How do I link between items in Qualtrics?

Tags: qualtrics

I have a block of 7 items in Qualtrics. Right now, I have it set up so it displays the first item to everyone, and then presents a random item from the next 5, and then presents the last item to everyone. The last item asks respondents to summarize what they read (which was one of the 5 random ones). 
I want them to be able to go re-read the item in case they weren't paying close enough attention.

Some ways of doing this might be:

1. Include a back button (but I'd want this to be the only place where they could go back), and I don't think it'd work anyway since I have randomization.
2. Include a link? (e.g. "To re-read the passage click here" and then something would pop up?) I don't know if there is a way to do this.
3. Include the last item on the same page as the randomized ones. It automatically broke them into separate pages - is there a way to include them in the same page?

If anyone knows how to do any of these, or has another suggestion, please help :)

Answer (score 1):

Put the 5 random items and the last item in the same block, then under block options choose Question Randomization.  Use Advanced Randomization to show 1 of the 5 random items, and show 2 items per page.